# C program no longer compiles in Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I made a program in C and I get these errors when I compile using gcc. I did not use to get them until recently and my program has not changed.

```
In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first   defined here
slots: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first   defined here
slots: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
slots:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0):   first defined here
slots: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first   defined here
slots: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first   defined here
/tmp/ccIlRWIn.o: In function `main':
slots.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
slots:(.text+0xe4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of  `__DTOR_END__'
slots:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in slots(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you post your makefile?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3695335/175849

Answer (score 6):

You forgot -o before the output filename so the linker is trying to use your old executable as input.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have more than one `main` and some other functions in your code. Make sure you didn't include multiple definitions of main more than once in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You could have probably defined an **extern** variable in a header file and include it in another file.

For example,

```
extern int _fini = 1;  // declared in a.h
```

Say in a1.c or a2.c

```
#include "a.h"   // _fini again defined in a1.c or a2.c
```